# Removing !important from css

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I am currently working on a wordpress website. Using woocommerce and this plugin called SMS Alert which allows to send OTP for Registration. This plugin has inserted extra field in my registration form with label 'Phone' and I've enabled dropdown list to select country code.

The problem is with the css.

```
<input type="tel" class="input-text phone-valid" name="billing_phone" id="reg_billing_phone" value="" placeholder="Enter Number Here" data-id="sa_intellinput_0" autocomplete="off" style="padding-left:1269px !important;">
```

The input field is very long because of the 'style' attribute in the code.

*style="padding-left:1269px !important;"*

And it's not going away. I want the padding-left to be 80px. I've tried the following:

1.

```
.page-id-2994 input#reg_billing_phone.input-text.phone-valid {
    width: 515px;
    padding-left: 80px !important;
}
```

2. Some Javascript as well from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713174/how-can-you-remove-an-important-css-property)
3. Also, I am not able to find the css file for this in file manager.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that is actually coming from some standard css? in my opinion that really looks something like JS-based so there's some script which is adding that inline style to your element. Try to reload the page w/o JS and see if that is still there or not

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the script to remove the inline style then you need not to use important in your css.
Just use:

```
document.getElementById('reg_billing_phone').removeAttribute('style');
```